# Putting comma between each word in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, replace

I have an NSString that is like @"nice car" and would like to create an NSString that is @"nice,car". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method to achieve this as follows:

```
NSString *stringWithSpaces = @"nice car";
NSString *stringWithCommas = [stringWithSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@","];
```